# debugging php when no notice/warning/error

Tags: php, debugging

Don't really know how to word this question. I have encountered this problem on several ocassasions.
The code does not generate any notice/warniong/error (it just dies) if:
1 I declare the same function name twice
2 I attempt to pass a constant to a by-reference parameter

The debugging can be quite tiresome as I have no idea what caused it and it may be a change made some time ago.

Any thoughts on:
How to prevent it?
Debugging techniques?

The code is running on a server rather than my own machine.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: make error_reporting(1);

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for error reporting :

```
 <?php 
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First,** you should enable error reporting in your PHP Script on the top line. 
using

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1); // Any syntax errors
```

**Second,** Apart from this you can not declare function with same name in the same class.

**Third,** Regarding pass a constant, it's because you can't pass a constant by reference there, and there would be no way to do. It is immutable. Constants are not variables.

The following things can be passed by reference:

1. Variables, i.e. foo($a) // foo is function
2. New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
3. References returned from function

No other expressions should be passed by reference.

**Fourth**, Always use Exception handling to manage the custom errors.

For more information how to pass by reference, Check the link [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the problem.
The issue is one of debugging, not what is allowed or disallowed.
I realise both the things I am trying to test for are not allowed.

Why does the code just stop running?

However they can happen in coding. The route to detect them seems very difficult. A simple error would be nicer. It appears this is not available.

is this a limitation of the language?

Comment: For simple or custom error, you have to use exception handling here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply paste top of the file

```
 <?php  error_reporting(0);?>
```

to supress all errors. Or use

```
 <?php  error_reporting(E_ALL);?>
```

to get meaningfull error messages.
More information on error reporting can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Well, that would supress error reporting. The OP might be more helped by actually printing errors instead of hiding them. Anyway, please always try to explain the meaning of code-only answers. Why should he post that in his code, what would be the effect?